# Adding email hash into facebook custom audience

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have no problem in creating Facebook Custom Audience using HTTP post operation equivalent to described in FB page:

```
// Create blank audience
curl \
-F "name=testAudience" \
-F "access_token=______" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345678/customaudiences"
```

But we cannot add email hash to the created custom audience.

```
// Add people
curl \
-F "users=[{'email_hash':'HASH'}, {'email_hash':'HASH'}, {'email_hash':'HASH'} …]" \
-F "access_token=_____" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/6005123456/users"
```

Although the response for post is *true*. According to FB document, "If the addition of the person succeeds, the API call will return true". But the availability for custom audience in the ads manager is always "Not Ready (File not updated)". No sign that email_hash was added. I can only upload csv to add people.

Does anyone have similar experience or know how to upload email_hash programmatically.

Comment: I had a very similar issue, and posted it with an answer here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393962/not-ready-file-not-uploaded-when-adding-to-facebook-custom-audience