# Not Ready: File Not Uploaded when adding to Facebook Custom Audience

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am attempting to add users to a Facebook Custom Audience using version 2.1 of their API.

I'm using this Python script to create a new audience, and add users to it.

```
import json, requests

# set up params
account_id = 'an ads account ID'
audience_name = 'a new name'
token = 'a valid access token'

# create a new audience ID for posterity
url =  "https://graph.facebook.com/act_" + account_id + "/customaudiences"
response = requests.post(url, {"name": audience_name, "access_token": token})
resp_dict = json.loads(response.content)
audience_id = resp_dict["id"]

# output new audience name and ID
print("For audience name of:", audience_name)
print("Created audience ID of:", audience_id)

# add email addresses to the audience
the_file = open("the.payload", "r")
payload = the_file.read()
the_file.close()

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/' + audience_id + '/users'
params = {"access_token": token, "payload": payload}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)

# output results
print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
print("Response content:", response.content)
```

A sample of the contents of "the.payload"  is:

```
{"data":["a8649fb702fb0a67e21ed5120a589cf4d15dd59e2eebb1ad606485731b124100","4842b7883df3c9048abbff1fddb3fd634bed474450f8b2b9102c4bf76fc33381"],"schema":"EMAIL_SHA256"}
```

Except, in my file, instead of having just 2 valid email addresses that have been formatted as SHA256, and written per hex, as per their docs, I have 1100 of them.

When I run this script, I receive:

```
('For audience name of:', 'the name I gave')
('Created audience ID of:', u'a valid ID number')
('Response status code:', 200)
('Response content:', '{"audience_id":"a valid ID number","num_received":1100,"num_invalid_entries":0,"invalid_entry_samples":[]}')
```

However, more than an hour later, "Not Ready, File not uploaded" shows in the UI for 100% of uploads done using this method. 
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to correct my code to add users to custom audiences successfully? I've reviewed Facebook's docs extensively, but I believe I'm following their format.

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be an issue with my hashing algorithm.

After posting this, I received a copy of an email hashing algorithm that was proven to work. It was this:

```
import hashlib
email = "somebody@somewhere.com"
email = email.strip().lower()
email = hashlib.sha256(email).hexdigest()
```

I compared the hash produced here to my own hash, and it wasn't coming out the same. After correcting it by stripping whitespace and not reusing a hasher in a loop, this problem resolved.

So, Not Ready can result from a hashing issue behind the scenes, or an upload containing too few valid & matching email addresses.